# Using GET parameters with clean urls

Tags: uri

I have module where I'm creating a custom path in hook_menu. When the user visits this page, they are supposed to be redirected to another site, with GET query parameters attached to the redirect URL. So for instance, if they visit `http://mysite.com/site-search?query=blah`, we are supposed to redirect them to `http://othersite.com/different-path?query=blah`.

However, we have clean URLs enabled; while I can hit the page `http://mysite.com/site-search`, it gives a page not found when I try to hit `http://mysite.com/site-search?query=blah`.

> The requested page "/site-search?query=blah" could not be found.

I tried adding another path for `site-search/%`, just to get that extra part of the URL, but that didn't work either.

Am I able to get the URL parameters while using clean URLs?

**Edit:** Here's the code:

```
function my_redirect_menu() {
  $items['site_search'] = array(
    'page callback' => 'my_redirect_redirect',
    'access callback' => TRUE, 
  );

  // testing to see if this will allow me to capture get parameters
  // in the form http://site.com/site_search/q=blah
  $items['site_search/%'] = array(
    'page callback' => 'my_redirect_redirect',
    'access callback' => TRUE, 
  );

  return $items;
}

function my_redirect_redirect() {
  // see if we can get the get paramters
  return "<pre>" . print_r($_SERVER,1) . "</pre>";
}
```

**Edit 2** In my example, I transcribed the query string in correctly. It looks like it's a conflict between drupal wanting to use `?q=` for its menu routing, and our search host URLs also using `?q=` for their queries. If I do `query=blah`, I am able to hit the page.

Comment: May you show the code used by the module? Without seeing it, it is not possible to say what is wrong. I am not clear why you are making an example for http://mysite.com/site-search?query=blah, but the error message is for /site-search?q=blah.

Comment: @Kiamlaluno in writing this question I transcribed my query strings incorrectly. It appears to be a conflict with both the drupal site and our search host wanting to use `?q=`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I use $_GET variables as needed in my clean-url installs without issue. Views uses $_GET variables, too. Drupal uses $_GET['q'] so you don't want to use that ID, but you should be able to do something like:

```
function my_redirect_menu() {
  $items['site_search'] = array(
    'page callback' => 'my_redirect_redirect',
    'access callback' => TRUE, 
    'type' => MENU_CALLBACK,
  );
  return $items;
}

function my_redirect_redirect() {
  return $_GET['query'];
}
```

This is working for me locally. The 2nd item you present in hook_menu only matches for /site_search/foo?query=bar so you only want the first. Be sure to set the `'type'` property as well.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry to be VERY late to the party. For anybody still looking for the answer:

```
function my_redirect_menu() {
    $items['site_search/%'] = array(
      'title' => 'Edit Product Details',
      'page callback' => 'my_redirect_redirect',
      'page arguments' => array(1),
      'access arguments' => array('access content')
    );
}

function my_redirect_redirect($id) {
   return t("your url % value was:".$id);
}
```